# In PhotoShop how do you create images with no bounding box background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What I mean, to put this in a horribly non-technical way, is if I'm drawing something like say a circle then when it's shown in my game I want it to just be a circle shape on the canvas, not have the white bounding box around it.

I'm using PhotoShop Corel X2 Ultimate. Is there a way I should save files or as a particular format so just the drawing is saved and the background is essentially 'transparent'.

Many thanks

Comment: You wouldn't handle this in PhotoShop, you can just save the image as a transparent bitmap (e.g. PNG). I'm not adding this as an answer however, because you need to give more information, for example about the programming language your want to use for your game.

Comment: Disregard my comment on SO; apparently migrated questions don't retain their vote scores. I still don't see the point on downvoting though.

Comment: @BoltClock: If you have under 3k reputation, you don't see the close vote count. I've given up trying to understand the myriad reasons some people choose to vote up or down. Fortunately, the "wisdom of the crowd" and careful weighting by the stackexchange crew tends to mitigate the effect of the outliers that will exist in almost any population.

Comment: @msw: I have > 3k rep on Stack Overflow. And good point about the "wisdom of the crowd" :)

Comment: @BoltClock: terrible place for this conversation, but I meant that other users who have less than 3k rep do not see the number of close votes, so downvoting (or flagging which hopefully they don't resort to) is the only tool for an under 3k rep to lazily express displeasure. Once you pass certain rep thresholds it is easy to forget that you see a different SE than others do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your image in a format that supports transparency.  For instance, GIF allows you to mark one color as 100% transparent; for some applications this will work, in other cases the image may appear to have jagged pixels.  The nicer way to do this is using PNG, which allows for each pixels to have a degree of transparency -- called the alpha channel.  Your circle will still be in a bounding box, but the 'background' will be transparent.